# Rails if url params exist update data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update a few `datetime columns` if the `url params exist`, in order to send email notifications later. Columns are: `first_expiration ,second_expiration, third_expiration` inside the `accounts table`. In the url I'm passing a couple of params: the current registering users `email` and the `plan_id`.

This is the setup I have inside the devise `registrations_controller`:

**Revised action:**

```
after_action :set_expiration, only: [:create]

def set_expiration
  if params.has_key?["plan_id"].present? == "nt127"
    @first_expiration = DateTime.now + 152.days
    @second_expiration = DateTime.now + 167.days
    @third_expiration = DateTime.now + 177.days
    current_client.account.update!(first_expiration: @first_expiration,
                                           second_expiration: @second_expiration,
                                           third_expiraton: @third_expiration)
  elsif params.has_key?["plan_id"].present? == "mli90"
    @first_expiration = DateTime.now + 335.days
    @second_expiration = DateTime.now + 350.days
    @third_expiration = DateTime.now + 360.days
    current_client.account.update!(first_expiration: @first_expiration,
                                         second_expiration: @second_expiration,
                                         third_expiraton: @third_expiration)
  end
end

def current_client
   if cookies["email"].present?
    User.find_by_email(cookies["email"])
   end
end
```

But if I check the console the update is not working. No errors are poping up and generally nothing is happening in regards to the update.

**Update 1**

This is my url:

```
http://localhost:3000/transactions/new?email=test11%40gmail.com&plan_id=ntl127&price=150.0
```

and I'm passing the params like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:email, params["email"]) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:plan_id, params["plan_id"]) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:amount, params["price"]) %>
```

Comment: This is in order to update the columns

Comment: Have you checked that there is actually a `"plan_id"` key in the root of your params? How does the params hash look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @spickermann, I added more info to my question, please check update!

Comment: You URL point to `/transactions/new` but the controller you in your post is named `registrations`. Are you sure that you actually hit the expected controller with the expected params? How does your log file for the request look like?

Comment: I had to put the action inside the `transactions_controller`... thanks for the help  @spickermann!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the `after_action` and the `set_expiration` to your `RegistrationsController`.

But if you followed common Rails idioms then your example URL which starts with `/transactions/new` would point to the `TransactionsController`.

Just move the method and the `after_action` to your `TransactionsController` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this
`elsif params["plan_id"] == "mli90"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anand, I changed the `else` to `elsif` but its still not updating..

Comment: I think you should use `update` instead of `update_attributes!` and you can also check by using `pry` or `debugger` at controller side.

Comment: it should be like this
`if params.["plan_id"].present? and  params.["plan_id"] == "nt127"`

`elsif params.["plan_id"].present?  and params.["plan_id"] == "mli90"`

Comment: [`update_attributes!`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes%21) is an alias for `update!` in Rails 4.2. Therefore both versions are valid. Using `update` without the `!` has the disadvantage that it would _not_ raise an exception if the record was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `.update!` instead of `.update_attributes!`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rony36, I added more in info to my question, please check revised action and update 1. Is it correct?

Comment: [`update_attributes!`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes%21) is an alias for `update!` in Rails 4.2. Therefore both versions are valid.

Comment: @Theopap how your `routes.rb` looks like regarding this `registration_controller`?